# Extended ASCII in C++

Tags: c++, ascii, extended-ascii

I've tried to execute the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned char datoChar = 168;
    cout << datoChar << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it returns a symbol with "?" but it should return "¿"

Comment: It all depends on the code page and Unicode support in the terminal

Comment: @phuclv is right. i think if you try any other extended ascii, then also maybe some of them will also turn into `?`

Comment: Use `wcout` instead: `wchar_t datoChar = L'¿'; wcout << datoChar << endl;` If you still have problems, check the charset of the console. There are tons of questions on StackOverflow related to Unicode console output.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified on which platform you are and what the current `locale` is, but its very likely that if you are running on a Unix-like operating system, the character is being interpreted by the terminal as being UTF-8 and not `cp437`. CP437, CP1252 and extended ASCII are nowadays mostly obsolete, and are only used in a DOS-like terminals such as Windows's `cmd.exe`. You may try switching to CP437 in CMD.EXE using the `CHCP` command.

In UTF-8, all bytes over `0x7f` are considered reserved, as they are used to implement multi-character encoding. In UTF-8, '¿' is codepoint U+00BF, and spans over two separate bytes.

You may get specify it into a literal by using the hexadecimal `\uXXXX` notation, such as in

```cpp
std::cout << "\u00BF" << std::endl;
```

Comment: _In UTF-8, all bytes over 0x79 are considered reserved_ Shouldn't it be 0x7f? Multi-byte sequences of UTF-8 are marked by the most significant bit set in all bytes. Hence, they become >= 0x80. Consequently, 0x7f is the highest value which is encoded without a multi-byte sequence.

Comment: @Scheff yep, you are correct. I subtracted 1 from 0x80 and I wrote 79 instead of 7f...